# typescript not recognising filtered array is all of one type with type guard

Tags: typescript

I have this code from [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20Page%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20heading%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20component%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20path%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20RouteOnly%20%3D%20Pick%3CPage%2C%20'heading'%20%7C%20'path'%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20routes%3A%20(Page%20%7C%20RouteOnly)%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20heading%3A%20'Home'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20'%2Fhome'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20component%3A%20'A'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20heading%3A%20'OSS'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20'%2Foss'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20component%3A%20'B'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20heading%3A%20'CV'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20'%2Fcv'%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20isPage(pageOrRoute%3A%20Page%20%7C%20RouteOnly)%3A%20pageOrRoute%20is%20Page%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20!!(pageOrRoute%20as%20Page).component%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20pages%3A%20Page%5B%5D%20%3D%20routes.filter((r)%20%3D%3E%20isPage(r))%3B%0D%0A)

```
export interface Page {
  heading: string;
  component: string;
  path: string;
}

export type RouteOnly = Pick<Page, 'heading' | 'path'>;


export const routes: (Page | RouteOnly)[] = [
  {
    heading: 'Home',
    path: '/home',
    component: 'A',
  },
  {
    heading: 'OSS',
    path: '/oss',
    component: 'B',
  },
  {
    heading: 'CV',
    path: '/cv'
  }
];

export function isPage(pageOrRoute: Page | RouteOnly): pageOrRoute is Page {
  return !!(pageOrRoute as Page).component;
}

const pages: Page[] = routes.filter((r) => isPage(r));
```

I would have thought that ts knows the `pages` array would only contain pages but ts complains:

> Property 'component' is missing in type 'Pick' but required in type 'Page'

Comment: `const pages: Page[] = routes.filter(isPage);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```js
export interface RouteOnly {
  path: string;
  heading: string;
}

// type Page = RouteOnly & { component: string };
export interface Page extends RouteOnly {
  component: string;
}

export const routes: (Page | RouteOnly)[] = [
  {
    heading: 'Home',
    path: '/home',
    component: 'A',
  },
  {
    heading: 'OSS',
    path: '/oss',
    component: 'B',
  },
  {
    heading: 'CV',
    path: '/cv'
  }
];

export function isPage(arg: unknown): arg is Page {
  return ({}).hasOwnProperty.call(arg || '', 'component');
}

const pages: Page[] = routes.filter(isPage);
```

Comment: These days I find guards like this most comprehensive: `export function isPage(arg: unknown): arg is Page {
  return typeof arg === 'object' && arg !== null && 'component' in arg;
}`